# My Delphi installation does not provide REST Client Module, even after creating a Datasnap REST Server

Tags: delphi

I have Delphi 10.2.2 and I have created a Datasnap REST Server successfully. Now I want to add a mobile app as the REST Client, but when I right-click the Project Group and choose Add New Project, these are the only options provided by the IDE:

- Datasnap REST Application
- Datasnap Server
- Datasnap WebBroker Application

There is nothing that shows Delphi REST Client Module (which is the one I require).

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The server must be running.

Comment: It is running already, but I still do not get the REST Client Module option. Any other ideas on what could cause this?

Comment: Have you review http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Developing_DataSnap_Applications and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Connecting_the_Client_to_DataSnap_Server and looked at the samples?  The client for a REST service can be anything; mobile, browser or IoT device. Check out the TSQLConnection class/component.

Comment: You need to create a new client project first. You can't add a client module to your server project!